# replacing a line in htm file with perl

Tags: perl, file, edit, editing

I am writing a script, it needs to open file go to a specific line and insert a string. This code works on txt files and htm files that I create, but when I try to use it on the real htm file, my strings just get added to the bottom of the file. Have to omit the actual strings and file locations.  I know there are prob modules that could make this easier but I try to learn how to do it on my own before going that route.

```
open( my $in,  "</Users/bal/Desktop/hold/r.txt" )   or die $!;
open( my $out, "+>/Users/bal/Desktop/hold/sr.txt" ) or die $!;

while (<$in>) {
    print $out $_;
    last if $. == 8;
}
my $liner = <$in>;
$liner = "ball\nball\n";
print $out $liner;
while (<$in>) {
    print $out $_;
}
```

Comment: Bad line endings in your real file?

Comment: I dont know htm code but it is a valid file and appears correct when I open it in the editor.

Comment: `perl -MData::Dumper -e'$Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; my $line = <>; print Dumper $line;' yourfile.htm` See what kind of line ending you have.

Comment: Then you currently have old Mac style line endings for that file.  If you're on unix or windows, then doing line by line will simply pull the entire file contents into the first line.  To fix line endings, you can use this perl command.  `perl -i -pe 's/\R/\n/g' r.txt`

Comment: I am currently working on a mac but this file will be parsed later on a windows and linux machines, will changing the end characters effect those machines or is the new ending accepted by all.

Comment: You're working with HTML, so line endings are actually somewhat irrelevant.  However, if `perl -E 'say $^O'` reports darwin, then I would *probably* choose to fix the line endings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're attempting to insert at line 9, but finding that the script is just appending, then most likely your line endings are for another system.

To inspect your file's line endings, you can try the following command:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -e '$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper scalar <>;' file
```

If you find they're incorrect, you can perhaps fix them using:

```
perl -i -pe 's|\R|\n|g' file
```

#### Working with HTML - use a parser

However, line numbers and line endings are somewhat irrelevant when it comes to HTML.

Instead, you should use an actual HTML parser like [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) to parse the html file and insert your text.  For a helpful 8 minute introductory video, you can check out [Mojocast Episode 5](http://mojocasts.com/e5).

The following demonstrates inserting a paragraph after the last `h2`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( do {local $/; <DATA>} );

$dom->at('h2:last-of-type')->append("\n<p>INSERTED - Paragraph ZERO</p>");

print $dom->to_string();

__DATA__
<html>
<head>
<title>Inserting a line</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Header one - Paragraph one</p>
<p>Header one - Paragraph two</p>
<p>Header one - Paragraph three</p>

<h2>What&apos;s up world?</h2>
<p>Header two - Paragraph one</p>
<p>Header two - Paragraph two</p>
<p>Header two - Paragraph three</p>

<h2>Goodbye world</h2>
<p>Header three - Paragraph one</p>
<p>Header three - Paragraph two</p>
<p>Header three - Paragraph three</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Inserting a line</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>Header one - Paragraph one</p>
<p>Header one - Paragraph two</p>
<p>Header one - Paragraph three</p>

<h2>What&#39;s up world?</h2>
<p>Header two - Paragraph one</p>
<p>Header two - Paragraph two</p>
<p>Header two - Paragraph three</p>

<h2>Goodbye world</h2>
<p>INSERTED - Paragraph ZERO</p>
<p>Header three - Paragraph one</p>
<p>Header three - Paragraph two</p>
<p>Header three - Paragraph three</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're going by line number in your test data. Have you considered using a regular expression to stick your extra line in the text file?

Remember that the live htm files might have a different live number count than the data you're working with. Instead consider using a pattern like:

```
$value = "ball\n";
$newValue = "ball\nball\n";
$line = s/$value/$newvalue
```

Stick this block of code into your loop where you process line-by-line. Then just print $out $line to replace the instance of "ball\n" with a new "ball\nball\n". By using regex, you should avoid the nastiness of counting line numbers in live data.

You can read yon perl regular expressions here:
https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html

There's also an entire book written about regular expressions, which I highly recommend.
[http://www.abebooks.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Powerful-Techniques-Perl/13660633427/bd?cm_mmc=gmc-*-gmc-*-PLA-_-v01](http://www.abebooks.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Powerful-Techniques-Perl/13660633427/bd?cm_mmc=gmc-_-gmc-_-PLA-_-v01)

That said, be very cautious when parsing htm files with regular expressions. 
Jeff Atwood wrote a compelling argument about how messy that can get.
http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

If you intend to do much more than substitute out a few lines, you'll probably want to look into a predefined library.

Comment: I replaced 'last if$.==8; with your block adding a g to the end to change all instances.  now I get a count of all instances of $value printed at the end of the file.   for clarity though I am editing a static file pushing out the edited version.  The file i edit will alawys be the same.